# Real time data value display in C#

Tags: c#, data-binding

Simple C# question: I was trying to design a simple C# DLL that uses a
third party library to stream images from a digital camera.

Really beginner C# programmer here, so bear with me through this question :)

I added a counter to the code so that whenever an image was retrieved
the counter incremented.

I built a pointless and simple GUI with a start and stop button to
make sure that everything was working properly because we were having
some problems in the past where the camera would stop streaming
suddenly, so I wanted to monitor this timer counter to make sure that
it is continuously incrementing.

What is the sensible way to do this to get a real time display of the
timer value? The value is just a UInt32 and is part of the object
instationed from the DLL.

What I actually implemented was sloppy:
I have a button that would pop up a message box displaying the timer
value when pressed, so to check if everything was still working, I
would press this button twice to make sure the value had incremented
somewhat.

What is the proper way to do this? Data binding? What would most of
you do in this simple case? I just want a label / textbox / anything
that will constantly refresh with the value of my counter data member.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest (assuming you can't just update when new data arrives) would be to add a forms timer to your form, and update the UI in the timer "tick" event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would have a [`Label`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx) control (assuming winforms) whose text property I would set to the value of the counter whenever it incremented.

```
counter++;
myLable.Text = counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

a label is very good approach but you have to make sure you are avoiding from application does not respond, so also add a line of code that lets the form process its queue

```
lblNumber.Text = number;
Application.DoEvents();
```