# Real time data value display in C#

Tags: c#, data-binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Real time data value display in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997227/real-time-data-value-display-in-c)

Simple C# question: I was trying to design a simple C# DLL that uses a
third party library to stream images from a digital camera.

Really beginner C# programmer here, so bear with me through this question :)

I added a counter to the code so that whenever an image was retrieved
the counter incremented.

I built a pointless and simple GUI with a start and stop button to
make sure that everything was working properly because we were having
some problems in the past where the camera would stop streaming
suddenly, so I wanted to monitor this timer counter to make sure that
it is continuously incrementing.

What is the sensible way to do this to get a real time display of the
timer value? The value is just a UInt32 and is part of the object
instationed from the DLL.

What I actually implemented was sloppy:
I have a button that would pop up a message box displaying the timer
value when pressed, so to check if everything was still working, I
would press this button twice to make sure the value had incremented
somewhat.

What is the proper way to do this? Data binding? What would most of
you do in this simple case? I just want a label / textbox / anything
that will constantly refresh with the value of my counter data member.

Thanks!

Comment: You asked this 40 minutes ago. What's wrong with the answers you got?

Answer (score 0):

everytime the counter is incremented just update a label or text box. then it will be "live".

```
    private int _counter = 0;
    public int counter
    {
       get { return _counter; }
       set { _counter = value; UpdateLabel(); }
    }

private void UpdateLabel()
{
   label1.Text = "Counter is: " + counter + " Last updated: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeStrong();
}
```

if the library has any events, then subscribe to those events to alert you as to what's going on.

Comment: Only works if the third-party code is updating his managed property. If the variable is located over in native code and he needs to "pull" it instead of it being "pushed", he'll need something else like a polling mechanism, or if he can, a callback.

Comment: @KeithS "I added a counter to the code so that whenever an image was retrieved the counter incremented." sounds like he's handling the counter

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to set up a polling mechanism; on your form, or even within your wrapper object, set up a timer that will fire its "tick" or "elapsed" event every 100 millis (1/10 second). Attach a handler to that event that will read the variable from the native code, and update a label or textbox with that value.

Comment: why poll when you can use events? polling isn't the proper way. Polling is only useful if you are polling the state of the device to determine if it's frozen.